# PHP decode JSON into selectmenu selected options

Tags: php, arrays, json, select

I want to get the options selected, i tried many ways and when i select an option from the list and after pressing submit the selectmenu points to the first element, which makes the option that i selected not actually selected. And i can't send what the user have chosen.

```
<?php 
    $operatorsAndPackages = $_SESSION['outputOperatorsAndPackages'];
    $json_a = json_decode($operatorsAndPackages,true);
?>

<label>Paquet : Opérateur : Montant</label><br/>

<select id="recharge_operator" name="recharge_operator">
<?php foreach ($json_a as $value): ?>       
    <?php echo $value; ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $value[paquet_id] . ":" . $value[code_operateur] . ":" . $value[montant_recharge]; ?>"><?php echo $value[paquet_id] . ":" . $value[code_operateur] . ":" . $value[montant_recharge]; ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the submitted value (I'll assume this is a POST operation in my code sample) and compare it to each assembled value in the loop to determine if the current is the same as what was submitted. If it is, you set the `selected` attribute of your `option` element.

Lines 13 and 16 of the following code sample are the most pertinent changes.

```
<?php 
    $operatorsAndPackages = $_SESSION['outputOperatorsAndPackages'];
    $json_a = json_decode($operatorsAndPackages,true);
?>

<label>Paquet : Opérateur : Montant</label><br/>

<select id="recharge_operator" name="recharge_operator">
<?php
    foreach ($json_a as $value)
    {
        $value = $value['paquet_id'] . ":" . $value['code_operateur'] . ":" . $value['montant_recharge'];
        $selected = ($value === $_GET['recharge_operator']);
        $html_safe_value = htmlentities($value);
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $html_safe_value; ?>"<?php if ($selected) {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?> >
        <?php echo $html_safe_value; ?>
    </option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>
```

I have a quick demo with source code available at: http://jaaulde.com/test_bed/SO_Lotus91/

Comment: It points to the last element in the menu and selects nothing.

Comment: I don't understand that comment. I suggest you debug by dumping the `$_GET` value, and in the loop dump each `$value` to take a look at what is getting compared.

Comment: @Lotus91, I apologize--I found the issue in what I suggested to you. I was outputting a `selected` attribute for all elements, and the browser acts on it if present at all--regardless of the value it holds. I have adjusted my answer to only output the attribute for the one which matches.

Comment: @Lotus91 did my edit to the answer move you any closer to your desired goal?

Comment: Nope, i still have the same problem, i can't keep any option selected

Comment: @Lotus91Hmm, ok. Please see the demo link I added to the end of my answer. It shows the idea working, and the code which is producing it. Outside of that, I don't have much other info I can offer based on the provided info.